# What does `class A B` mean?

Tags: c++

I met an error complaining: `error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token`

SO I went to check the code, it has some lines as below,

```
class VTK_IO_EXPORT vtkPFReader
:
    public vtkMultiBlockDataSetAlgorithm
{blahblah...}
```

I want to know in defining `class VTK_IO_EXPORT vtkPFReader`, what does the first name `VTK_IO_EXPORT` mean? I found that if I delete the `VTK_IO_EXPORT`, then no error occurs, but some other error happens. What should I do? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`VTK_IO_EXPORT` is a preprocessor macro. It is blank on all platforms other that Windows.

On Windows, `VTK_IO_EXPORT` [is defined](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/4.2/html/vtkWin32Header_8h-source.html#l00140) as [`__declspec( dllexport )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [`__declspec( dllimport )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), both of which are non-standard Microsoft extensions.

The fact that you're getting the error, and that removing `VTK_IO_EXPORT` fixes it, suggests that for some reason you have `WIN32` defined even though you're building on Linux. You need to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: @Daniel One does not simply compile this code using GCC. Aside the joke: remove the Windows-specific clutter and it'll be fine.

Comment: You mean if I am using linux, I can simply delete this `VTK_IO_EXPORT`?

Comment: @Daniel yes you can, by all means

Comment: Why did `error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token` appear?

Comment: One shouldn't delete the macro, but make sure that it is defined (to be empty if need be). Check where it is defined, I'd expect something like vtk_io_export.h etc.

Comment: @ Frank Osterfeld - Something says that you are right - "And more recently, GCC visibility in newer versions of GCC. It decorates
class declarations with the correct attributes to be exported (and on Windows imported) in shared libraries (DLLs, .so, .dylib etc). Internal classes do not need it, but anything that can be called as part of our API his macro before it."(http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.vtk.user/45751)

Comment: @Daniel: The parser sees `class A B` and interprets that as a class declaration and variable definition, similar to `class A; A B` - and it expects either a semicolon or an initializer for B. That is not very common in real code, because you can't define B without having class A defined - and if you had, you would simply write `A B` and leave out the `class`. Hope that descritption is not too confused ;)

Answer (score 4):

VTK_IO_EXPORT is a macro, probably for an **attribute**. You should find where it's defined and that should make things clearer (or at least easier to google)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `VTK_IO_EXPORT` is all caps indicates that it's a macro. Typically libraries stick an 'export' macro in that location so that on Windows they can insert `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` at that location in order to export their interface in Windows DLLs.

The build system probably has not correctly defined this macro so you're getting an error. You should see where the macro is supposed to be defined and trace backwards until you find where something in the build is incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `VTK_IO_EXPORT` is a macro. And since it is a macro, it can be anything. It can be just empty whitespace.

So, it is really you who should tell us what it means. Look up the definition of that macro in the code and see what it is substituted with.

Answer (score 1):

this is a MSVC extension enclosed in a macro:

```
#if defined(vtkIO_EXPORTS)
 #define VTK_IO_EXPORT __declspec( dllexport ) 
#else
 #define VTK_IO_EXPORT __declspec( dllimport ) 
#endif
```

You solve it by using the above define or including `vtkWin32Header.h` - you'll get it with the distribution package.